# How to check if a node has particular class in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I regularly hide/show nodes through JavaScript, but now I need to set those of a specific class `inline-block` (not `block`) when showing. However, I have a problem with sorting the `inline-block` class and the rest, the `class` is null in this context:

```
show: function (div) {
    if (typeof div === 'object' && typeof div.style === 'object') {
        if (div.class == "inline-block-class") //this doesn't work
        {
            div.style.display = "inline-block";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

The `div`s are referenced by `data-dojo-attach-point` - I can work with something like `this.someAttachPoint` completely, but when I wrap it into some other variable (such as `div` in my function), I get only the CSS selectors of the node - it's an object, but I can't get its properties in FireBug.

I can workaround this by adding another parameter, a flag telling me that this node should be `inline-block`, but it's dirty and another opportunity for errors, so I would prefer to do the `block`/`inline-block` distinction within the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [dojo/dom-class](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-class.html) and [dojo/dom-style](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-style.html) modules to check the class on a DOM node and change the style.

```
show: function (div) {
if (typeof div === 'object' && typeof div.style === 'object') {
    if (domClass.contains(div, "inline-block-class"))
    {
        domStyle.set(div, 'display', 'inline-block');
    } else {
        domStyle.set(div, 'display', 'block');
    }
}
}
```

Better solution to this is to control the `div.style.display` using the CSS and not Javascript. Just change the classes in Javascript and let CSS handle the styling.

Comment: About the last sentence, I function hide(div) setting display to none is complementary to this one, so pure CSS approach seems unapplicable in my case; hiding divs without setting display:none is something I don't know how to do, and I don't care much if renewing proper display style is quite easy.

Comment: For each state, define a class. Such as `invisible` for `display: none`, `inline-block-class` for `display: inline-block` and `block-class` for `display: block`. And now, just manipulate the classes in Javascript, the CSS will get changed automatically.

Comment: The approach from your comment makes sense - just define hidden class with display none !important and add it and remove it as I hide and show the node.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property of the DOM element `div`, It expose's a method `contains`.

> Checks if specified class value exists in class attribute of the element.

```
if (div.classList.contains("inline-block-class")) 
{
    div.style.display = "inline-block";
} else {
    div.style.display = "block";
}
```